# DisplayFor not working with same model name with different namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, razor

I've run into an issue where I'm unable to call the correct DisplayTemplate.

I have two models:

```
CompanyName.Application.Web.Controllers.SharedViewModels.PaymentItemViewModel
CompanyName.Application.ViewModels.SharedViewModels.PaymentItemViewModel
```

These objects are used within an IEnumerable and then passed to a DisplayTemplate.

DisplayTemplates/PaymentItemViewModel.cshtml:

```
@model CompanyName.Application.ViewModels.Web.SharedViewModels.PaymentItemViewModel
```

DisplayTemplates/PaymentItems.cshtml:

```
@model CompanyName.Application.Web.Controllers.SharedViewModels.PaymentItemViewModel
```

If I try to call the display template of PaymentItems.cshtml like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PaymentItems, "DisplayTemplates/PaymentItem")
```

it throws an error where it's complaining that the model passed into the dictionary is not the same model type that the dictionary was expecting.  The types in model.PaymentItems are definitely an IEnumerable of

```
CompanyName.Application.Web.Controllers.SharedViewModels.PaymentItemViewModel
```

The other template does work if I call like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PaymentItems)
```

however if I specify the template name:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PaymentItems, "DisplayTemplates/PaymentItemViewModel.cshtml")
```

then it fails.  It's as if specifying the template name is either ignored altogether or it breaks the template functionality.

Comment: If I try to call the display template of PaymentItems.cshtml like so: gives you a legitamate answer makesure you use IEnumerable PaymentItems

Comment: It is an IEnumerable.  The one I use for the ViewModels.SharedViewModels one is in an IList though and does actually work.

Comment: than you are not passing IList

Comment: You can also use the DataAnnotations attribute UIHint("") and annotate the property and specify which template to use ex. [UIHint("PaymentItem")] public IEnumerable<PaymentItem> PaymentItems { get;set; }. Also, I think the view name string you are passing is incorrect. If you have the display templates inside your controllers' view folder or the shared folder (Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates), then you only need to specify the view name ex. "PaymentItem".

Answer (score 0):

Shelakel's comment on the question half answered the question for me.

I changed the "DisplayTemplates/PaymentItem" to be just "PaymentItem" and it begun calling the correct template.  However, it did raise another issue, where it was complaining that it was trying to pass an IList into the individual object.

This is how the PaymentItems looks on the main model:

```
private IList<PaymentItemViewModel> paymentItems = new List<PaymentItemViewModel>();

public IEnumerable<PaymentItemViewModel> PaymentItems
{
    get { return paymentItems; }
    set { paymentItems = value.ToList(); }
}
```

To resolve the issue I had to make the model on the display template an IList and put a foreach inside it.  Kinda pointless really as I thought one of the main reasons of templates is that you don't need to loop through collections on the views!

Anyway, I believe the IList issue stems from the fact the initial collection starts life as an IList, but I have got it working now so I guess the question is answered.

Changing the paymentItems declaration from `IList<PaymentItemViewModel` to `IEnumerable<PaymentItemViewModel>` doesn't change anything.